# remove duplicate values from while loop array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, arraylist, duplicates

I have a while loop,and data has been selected from database. i want to remove duplicate data from while loop, that is already inserted while loop array not included in the next while loop iteration.

```
while ($age = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ages)) {
            print_r($age);
        }
echo "<br>";



output :   

Array
(
   [age] => 30
   [user_id] => 52
)
"<break point>"

 Array
(
    [age] => 29
    [user_id] => 58
)
Array
(
   [age] => 30
   [user_id] => 52
)
 Array
 (
   [age] => 28
   [user_id] => 74
 )

  "<break point>"

  Array
(
  [age] => 29
  [user_id] => 58
)
Array
  (
  [age] => 30
   [user_id] => 52
 )
"<break point>"
```

the problem is first while loop included user_id 52, and also next loop also includes user_id 52.

i want to remove duplicate user_id from while loop. is any method to remove duplicate values from while loop.

Comment: `loop ... next loop`  - are loops results of diff qurey?

Comment: no same query..

Comment: this is the first loop query
Array
(
   [age] => 30
   [user_id] => 52
)
"<break point>"

Comment: what does `"<break point>"` mean?

Comment: `select distinct age, id ....`

Comment: just to show you <br> break ...

Comment: echo <br> is outside the loop

Comment: splash, i select data from database with min and max range . when select min_age to 25 and max_age to 30. then it fetch all data that between 25 and 30. ,right? if another range min_age to 28 and max_age to 30 . then it show already insert value in previous loop.

Comment: You should save id shown anywhere (f.e. in array, or session if that is after reloading page) and later test new data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT` while `querying` with database OR use `$unique_array=array_unique($array_after_query)` after query for removing duplicates

Try this one in your case :

```
$unique_array=array_unique($array_after_query, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: array_unique won't work here on a multi-dimensional array (aggregation aside).

Comment: Better!  But the OP is fetching by row.  You haven't shown the aggregation beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($ages as $age) {
        if($age == $ages[i]) {
            unset($age);
            // OR REMOVE IT BY YOUR METHOD
        }
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Where `$ages` is your array.